# Add data to ArrayList android

Tags: android, json

In logcat I am getting a `null pointer exception` for this code sample. I am trying to add the e.g `oneObject.has(TAG_TITLE)` inside an `Arraylist` but when I print `currentPost.getid()` for example i am getting this `nullpointer excepttion`. Can someone help me please.

// getting JSON string from URL

```
JSONArray jArray = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
ArrayList<Post> PostList = new ArrayList<Post>();
Post currentPost = new Post();

// looping through All element
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
    try{
        JSONObject  oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // Storing each json item in variable
        if(oneObject.has(TAG_ID)){
            id = oneObject.getString(TAG_ID);
            currentPost.setId(id);
        }
        else{
            id="";
        }
        if(oneObject.has(TAG_TITLE)){
            title = oneObject.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            currentPost.setTitle(title);
        }
        else{
            title ="";
        }
        if(oneObject.has(TAG_CONTENT)){
            content = oneObject.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
            currentPost.setContent(content);
        }
        else{
            content ="";
        }
        System.out.println("postlist: "+currentPost.getId());
        PostList.add(currentPost);
        currentPost = new Post();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need to set  currentPost object fields values to default value if key name not exist in Json String as :

```
           // your code here...
            if(oneObject.has(TAG_ID)){

                id = oneObject.getString(TAG_ID);

                currentPost.setId(id);
            }
            else{

                id="DEFAULT_VALUE";
                currentPost.setId(id);  //<<<< set default value here
            }
           // your code here...
```

Comment: @sophia : put `currentPost.setId(id);System.out.println("postlist: "+currentPost.getId());` code inside else part and check you are getting value in log or not

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
// Storing each json item in variable

                    if(oneObject.has(TAG_ID)){

                        id = oneObject.getString(TAG_ID);

                        currentPost.setId(id);
                    }
                    else{

                        id="";
                    }
```

You have missed to set the Id for current `oneObject.has(TAG_ID)` returns false.

Best way to avoid this would be to return empty string from all your getters if the parameter is not being set.

EDIT:

Add make the change that is in bold.

// Storing each json item in variable

```
                    if(oneObject.has(TAG_ID)){

                        id = oneObject.getString(TAG_ID);

                        currentPost.setId(id);
                    }
                    else{

                        id=""; 
                        **currentPost.setId(id);**
                    }
```

Comment: i don't understand, elaborate please

Comment: You are setting the post id by calling `currentPost.setId(id)` if `oneObject.has(TAG_ID)` is true but not setting it when it is false. Check my answer I have edited it.